# VB.NET Try/Catch doesn't catch exception in runtime

Tags: vb.net, try-catch

I am compiling a console application that for some reason stopped catching exceptions.  As a test, I put the following:

```
Sub Main()
    Try
        Log = New LogWriter("C:\app.log")
        Log.Log("Test:")
        Dim a As Single = 5 / 0
        Dim b As Object
        Log.Log(b.ToString)
    Catch exTest As Exception
        Log.Log("Caught exception")
    End Try
End Sub
```

(where LogWriter is a custom class I wrote to control log output)  So, what happens when I run it as a compiled EXE on the target machine (no Visual Studio)?  I get the line "Test:" in the log, then:

Unhandled Exception:  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Why?  What did I do to disable exception handling?

Comment: Could it be that the `Log` object is somehow defective, such that `Log.Log` itself throws an NRE?  The first call would throw an exception which would be caught, but the call within the Catch handler itself would throw another exception, and that one wouldn't be caught.

Comment: This is all entirely normal, the b.ToString() method fails with NRE because b is Nothing.  If you were hoping to get an exception from the division by zero then that was idle hope, that's valid and has a well-defined result of Infinity.  And beyond.

Comment: Yes, I put those 2 lines in on purpose to generate an exception, the problem is that the Catch doesn't catch it.  It's driving me crazy, I can't figure out why Try/Catch doesn't work anymore throughout the project.  I created a brand new Project, added all the code, and it exhibits the same behavior; but if I create a brand new project with brand new code in the same solution, it does catch the exception and handle in the Catch block.  If I remove Try/Catch and use On Error GoTo, this does catch the exception.

Comment: @supercat, the LogWriter class is fine, that is working fine.  In fact, the exception that is raised is exactly the same if you replace the line with "MsgBox(b.ToString)" - so you can just ignore the Log.Log...

Comment: OK, this is REALLY strange!  I created a whole new startup module for the Console app to run, and voila, exception caught.  So I added all the Imports statements, and voila, exception not caught.  I narrowed it down, and the only namespace that causes thrown exceptions to not be caught is Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime.  I have a bunch of other AutoDesk.* namespaces that don't cause this issue.  For some reason, this one namespace breaks the exception catching mechanism - it is from ObjectARX 19 (AutoCAD 2013).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Infinity is a valid value for floats.

```
    Private Sub Test_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Try
        Log("C:\app.log")
        Dim a As Single
        a = 5 / 0
        Log("Test zero: " & a)
        Dim b As Object
        Log(b.ToString)
        Log("Test null")
    Catch exTest As Exception
        Log("Caught exception" & vbCrLf & exTest.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
Sub Log(msg As String)
    Debug.Print(msg)
End Sub
```

Results:

```
C:\app.log
Test zero: Infinity
Caught exception
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

b was not instantiated hence the error.

Comment: If you read the problem description, I don't want to know why the code raises the exception - I want to know why the Catch block doesn't handle it when raised.  The program, both in Debug and runtime, gives an Unhandled Exception.  However, replacing Try/Catch with On Error GoTo works.  This is not an option, because I have many nested Try/Catch blocks throughout the code that has worked fine for 4 years.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my app needed to manipulate AutoCAD drawings.  Adding a reference to the namespace Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime interrupted the try/catch mechanism for some reason.  I removed that namespace and left the references to the other namespaces, and it works.